# Bayesian Update for two Normal Random Variables following one observation of difference between them

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution

Let's say we have a Normal Random Variable with unknown mean and variance. We want to estimate the mean and variance given a normal choice for a prior and some data. Let's call it `X`.

Also there's another Normal Random Variable, also with unknown mean and variance It has it's own prior, which can be similarly parameterized. Let's call it `Y`.

Then we observe the following: `d = x - y` where `x` and `y` are occurrences of `X` and `Y` respectively. We don't actually know what `x` and `y` are; all we see is `d`. We wish to update the hyperparameters of `X` and `Y` based on observing this data.

My questions are:

1. Is this a known problem with a solution worked out?
2. If not, does anyone have any ideas of how to attack it?

Answer (score 1):

If $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_X, \sigma_X^2)$ and $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_Y, \sigma_Y^2)$, and $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then

$$ X-Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_X-\mu_Y, \sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2) $$

so [difference of two normals is also normally distributed](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalDifferenceDistribution.html).

This means that your question simplifies to asking how many real numbers $a,b$ such that $a-b = c$ exist, and how many real numbers $d,e$ such that $d+e=f$ exist? In both cases you have unlimited number of possibilities. So the model you describe is not identifiable (there is no unique solution for it) and it cannot be estimated.

***Notice:*** As *Glen_b* noted in the comments (see comments under this answer), theoretically it may be possible to estimate such model when using *informative* priors, however I do not see how it could be implemented.

#### Comment to code posted by *adamwlev* in answer to his question

*Answers are not meant to comment other answers, but there is too much to be said to use comments for it, so I'm going to refer to the code in my answer. Moreover, while OP considers his solution to answer the question, it seems that commenting it also answers his misconceptions about mentioned model.*

First, notice that your code ***doesn't work***. To convince yourself, try using *realistic* example for testing the code that in fact *is* a difference of two normals and check if your code correctly finds the appropriate parameters. For example, try the following data and check if the parameters are recovered

```r
ds <- c(rnorm(200,7,10) - rnorm(200,2,10)) ##simulated data
```

...they will not. But, as *Glen_b* noticed, Bayesian estimation can work in here by employing *prior*, out-of-data knowledge into the model to facilitate identifiability. Let's make one more change in your code and assume *perfect knowledge* about the searched parameters, where your priors are *equal* to the true parameters, so the model should not have any problems with finding them (as they are known in advance). So, let's change the following lines:

```r
p_x <- dnorm(x,7,10)/sum(dnorm(x,7,10)) ##prior probabilities for X
p_y <- dnorm(y,2,10)/sum(dnorm(y,2,10)) ##prior probabilities for Y
```

It ***will diverge from the initial correct values*** assumed in *priors*. In fact, it doesn't work exactly for the reason outlined in my answer: such model is not identifable.

The presented algorithm *does not* estimate the model described in the question. The model that was described was

$$
X_i \sim \mathrm{Normal}(\mu_X, \sigma_X^2) \\
Y_i \sim \mathrm{Normal}(\mu_Y, \sigma_Y^2) \\
D_i = X_i - Y_i \sim \mathrm{Normal}(\mu_X-\mu_Y, \sigma_X^2 + \sigma_Y^2)
$$

while the model described in the algorithm is something closer to

$$
X_i \sim \mathrm{Normal}(\mu_X, \sigma_X^2) \\
Y_i \sim \mathrm{Normal}(\mu_Y, \sigma_Y^2) \\
D_i \sim \mathrm{Normal}(X_i - Y_i, \sigma_D^2)
$$

So $D$ in here is *not* a random variable that is a difference of two other random variables $X,Y$, but instead you have $n$ random variables $D_i$ where each of them has *different* mean equal to $X_i-Y_i$, where you have *only one observation* per each random variable $D_i$. So in fact from single datapoint you want to estimate two parameters, $X_i,Y_i$ -- you have not identifable model and insufficient data for this. Moreover, calling *exactly the same* likelihood twice

```r
p_x1 <- rowSums(outer(p_x,p_y)*dnorm(d,outer(x,y,"-"),liklihood_shape))
p_x1 <- p_x1/sum(p_x1)
p_y1 <- colSums(outer(p_x,p_y)*dnorm(d,outer(x,y,"-"),liklihood_shape))
p_y1 <- p_y1/sum(p_y1)
```

won't lead you to calculate different parameters...

Comment: But it does contain information and we can update the information we have. Imagine I start with a prior on a pair of variables (W and Z say) with variance L and L respectively (for L very large) and I observe 1 observation on one of the components (W). I can update the distribution of the mean of that component. Now let W be X-Y and Z be X+Y and we have the essentials of the present situation -- we have obtained an observation about a component of a transformed version of the problem. It should not be impossible to incorporate what that information tells us

Comment: I'm brought to mind of a paper by Kohn and Ansley (I think) on updating a state space model with initial state that has infinite variances - it does pretty much the sort of updating that I'm thinking of ... I'll see if I can recall the title. It updates the diffuse components as information comes in

Comment: Craig F. Ansley and Robert Kohn (1985),  $\:$
"Estimation, Filtering, and Smoothing in State Space Models with Incompletely Specified Initial Conditions", $\:$ 
*Ann. Statist.*, Vol. 13, No. 4, pp 1286-1316.  $\:$
https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1176349739 $\quad$ (There's also a somewhat later paper by Piet de Jong on a similar topic)

Comment: @Glen_b I see your point, that's interesting. When I find some spare time I'll take a look at the papers. Maybe you would be willing to provide answer to this Q?

Comment: Unfortunately I won't have time to go back and sort it out for days at least; it's a paper I read in the early 90s, not material I have in my head.

Comment: @Glen_b I have done basically what you suggested. My bare bones version is just to define a PMF of each variable and then update each PMF after each observation of d observed. In the simple case of just two variables, the posterior means end up being opposite of one another. I can post my R code if anyone would like.

Comment: @adamwlev You were updating covariance as well?

Comment: @ Glen_b No, I am working under the assumption that there is no covariance between the variables which suits my applied problem. Also, I've just realized that I neglected to mention that we can have some likelihood function to work with - f(D|difference in X and Y). So basically I just discretized a normal distribution. It's seems to work fine.

Comment: But the *parameters* are what you're estimating; they can have a covariance

Comment: @adamlew if it works for you, you can post it as answer to your question. It would be interesting.

Comment: @Glen_b yeah, that is interesting. I guess that would be a more proper treatment of what I am trying to do. By just discretizing the variables and updating accordingly, I have sidestepped estimating the parameters directly, instead doing so implicitly.

Comment: @Tim I will post my code. Would appreciate feedback from you guys to improve the procedure.

Comment: 1/2 Wow, I sincerely did not mean to pick a fight here. One thing that I want to reemphasize is that I do not consider my hacky solution to be an answer to the theoretical way one would properly make inferences about the model I originally asked about. I thought I made that clear above. I went away from the theoretical model and approximated the normal random variables with a discrete random variable defined on some arbitrary range with density values form a normal and then normalized to sum to 1. A side effect of this is that when you try to define X with values from a normal with mean 7...

Comment: 2/2 over a range of -12 to 12, the mean of the discrete RV that results is actually 2.68. If you were to extend this range outwards sufficiently, the mean converges to what was meant to be specified. So your proposed experiment runs correctly if you just extend the possible values that x can take on. Again, I just want to say that I had in mind a practical solution that can handle an applied problem decently. Apologies that I diverged from the original question. I appreciate your help is thinking through the problem.

Comment: @adamwlev so try *any* other values, e.g. 1 and 3, it diverges.

Answer (score 0):

I have coded up a start towards answering the question. I assume independence of X and Y (which happens to suit my problem).

My approach was to discretize the two random variables X and Y and then update the probabilities upon observing data. I think this is like Approximate Bayes Computation. I needed a likelihood function which dictates how likely it is to observe a value given a difference in X and Y. I specified this to be a normal RV.

R Code:

```
require(colorRamps)

x <- seq(-300,300)/25 ##possible values of now discrete RV X
p_x <- dnorm(x,0,10)/sum(dnorm(x,0,10)) ##prior probabilities for X
y <- seq(-300,300)/25 ##possible values of Y
p_y <- dnorm(y,0,10)/sum(dnorm(y,0,10)) ##prior probabilities for Y

## this is the standard deviation of the liklihood function.
## it specifies how much information should be gleaned from
## any single observation of d.
liklihood_shape <- 60

## updates with bayes' formula. calculates posterior for each
## discrete value of X and Y given the liklidhood of the data
## under the joint distribution X and Y (assuming independence).
update <- function(x,p_x,y,p_y,d){
    p_x1 <- rowSums(outer(p_x,p_y)*dnorm(d,outer(x,y,"-"),liklihood_shape))
    p_x1 <- p_x1/sum(p_x1)
    p_y1 <- colSums(outer(p_x,p_y)*dnorm(d,outer(x,y,"-"),liklihood_shape))
    p_y1 <- p_y1/sum(p_y1)
    return(list(p_x1,p_y1))
}

ds <- c(rnorm(200,-2,7)) ##simulated data
colorsX = blue2red(length(ds)+1)
colorsY = magenta2green(length(ds)+1)
plot(x,p_x,type='l',col=colorsX[1],ylim=c(0,.007)) ##plot the prior of X
plot(y,p_y,type='l',col=colorsY[1],ylim=c(0,.007)) ##plot the prior of Y
for (d in 1:length(ds)){ ##update the data and plot posteriors for each datum
    res = update(x,p_x,y,p_y,ds[d])
    p_x = res[[1]]
    p_y = res[[2]]
    lines(x,p_x,col=colorsX[d+1])
    lines(y,p_y,col=colorsY[d+1])
}
```

Comment: The main comment is that *it doesn't work*. Try defining X and Y as normal variables with equal sd's and different means, say -3 and 7. Then set prior means to the same values. You will notice that the posterior would "converge" to symmetric means that are far from the true/prior means no matter that you started with the correct values.

Comment: @Tim hmm, I don't quite understand what you mean. So set the prior on X and Y to be centered around -3 and 7 respectively. Then do what?

Comment: Your code is **wrong**. I provided extended comment to it in my answer.